# Adding plus/minus to bootstrap panel

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

Consider the following snippet of `jQuery` code

```
function toggleIcon(e) {
   $(e.target)
   .prev('.panel-heading')
   .find(".more-less")
   .toggleClass('glyphicon-plus glyphicon-minus');
}
$('.panel-group').on('hidden.bs.collapse', toggleIcon);
$('.panel-group').on('shown.bs.collapse', toggleIcon);
```

The above code is inside `$(document).ready(function(){});`

the markup looks like:

```
   <div class="panel-group" id="collapse">
    <div class="panel panel-primary">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <h4 class="panel-title"><a data-parent="#collapse" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapse-one"><i class="more-less glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i> Item Details
            <span class="badge pull-right" id="itemdetails">0</span></a></h4>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-collapse collapse in" id="collapse-one">
            <div class="panel-body">
                @for (int i = 0; i < Model.MyList.Count; i++) {
                <div class="panel panel-info">
                    <div class="panel-heading">
                        <h4 class="panel-title"><a data-toggle="collapse"
                        href="#@Model.MyList[i].Number"><i class="more-less glyphicon glyphicon-plus">@Model.MyList[i].Number, @Model.MyList[i].PropA, @Model.MyList[i].PropB</i></a></h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="panel-collapse collapse" id="@Model.MyList[i].Number">
                        <div class="panel-body"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        }
    </div>
</div>
```

This works for every panel apart from the first one. The first panel will always be open and instead of adding a plus it adds a minus. The first panel has the class `panel-collapse collapse in` which ensure the panel is opened on the page load.

Please note, I have nested panels and this also works well for those too, its only the first panel which is causing me problems

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong please.

Comment: Post the relevant HTML too

Comment: @ZimSystem I've updated my OP

Answer (score 0):

I have tried this Please refer below code:

**HTML**:

```
<div class="panel-group" id="accordion">

  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseTwo">
           Collapsible Group Item #2 
        </a><i class="indicator glyphicon glyphicon glyphicon-plus  pull-right"></i>
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseTwo" class="panel-collapse collapse">
      <div class="panel-body">
        Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseThree">
          Collapsible Group Item #3 
        </a><i class="indicator glyphicon glyphicon glyphicon-plus pull-right"></i>
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseThree" class="panel-collapse collapse">
      <div class="panel-body">
        Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**JavaScript Code:**

```
$('#accordion').on('hidden.bs.collapse', function () {
    //do something...
})
$('#accordion .accordion-toggle').click(function (e) {
    var chevState = $(e.target).siblings("i.indicator").toggleClass('glyphicon-minus glyphicon-plus');
    $("i.indicator").not(chevState).removeClass("glyphicon-minus").addClass("glyphicon-plus");
});
```

Please refer this [fiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/adminsunil/gn0wgvt0/) for demo.

Comment: This will have the same problem. If you add the class `in` to the div with id `collapseTwo` then the result is exactly the same as what I'm facing. As I mentioned in my OP the first panel has to stay open on page load I can't have it closed. If the first panel if closed then my code works perfectly fine. But it's one of the requirements to keep the panel open

Comment: check this updated fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/adminsunil/gn0wgvt0/1/